# Plotting a 2d color plot using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Can someone please help me generate a 2d color plot using MatPlotLib?
I am trying to plot a function removal_fraction(P_inlet,T_inlet,P_tank) where P_tank is constant.

Here is my code:

```
def removal_fraction(P_inlet,T_inlet,P_tank):
    #Pressure in flash tank is P_tank, in Pa(a)
    
    #Enthalpy of sap before flash tank
    H_inlet=cp.PropsSI('H',"P",P_inlet,"T",T_inlet,"water") #J/kg

    #Sensible enthalpy of sap once in the tank
    H_sensible_tank=cp.PropsSI('H',"P",P_tank,"Q",0,"water") #J/kg

    #Heat lost to latent vaporization in the tank
    Latent_heat_transferred=H_inlet-H_sensible_tank #J/kg

    #Latent enthalpy of vaporization of sap in the tank (J/kg)
    H_latent_tank=cp.PropsSI('H',"P",P_tank,"Q",1,"water")-cp.PropsSI('H',"P",P_tank,"Q",0,"water") #J/kg

    #Proportion of water evaporated
    R_water_evap=Latent_heat_transferred/H_latent_tank #kg water/kg water
    return R_water_evap

P_inlet=np.linspace(200000,100000*40,500) #Pa(a)
T_inlet=np.linspace(90+273.15,200+273.15,500) #K
P_tank=(14.7-10)*6894.76 #Pa(a)

#Creating the 2D grid
P_inlet_vals,T_inlet_vals=np.meshgrid(P_inlet,T_inlet,indexing='ij')
Removal_fraction=np.zeros((len(P_inlet_vals),len(T_inlet_vals)))
#Computing removal_fraction for each point in the grid
for i in range(len(P_inlet)):
    for j in range(len(T_inlet)):
        Removal_fraction[i,j]=removal_fraction(P_inlet_vals[i,j],T_inlet_vals[i,j],P_tank)
```

What I want to plot is the removal fraction as a function of P_inlet and T_inlet. I am having difficulties coming up with my removal fraction array. The Propssi functions will not take in an array. So I must pass each value in using a for-loop. I'm not sure how this array must be constructed to be plotted properly on a 2D color plot.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

To plot it as a 2D grid you need to 'expand' Pinlet and Tinlet into a 2D grid, and then compute removal_fraction for each point on that grid. Example below. (Updated to use contour plots rather than `imshow` as per the suggestion from @Cornelia).

[image]

```
import numpy as np

#Generate some test data
p_inlet = np.linspace(200000, 100000 * 40, 500) #Pa(a)
t_inlet = np.linspace(90 + 273.15, 200 + 273.15, 500) #K
p_tank = 0.6

#Create a grid out of the x and y values
p_inlet_grid, t_inlet_grid = np.meshgrid(p_inlet, t_inlet)

#Compute removal_frac for each point in the grid
removal_frac = p_inlet_grid / t_inlet_grid * np.sinc(t_inlet_grid / t_inlet_grid.max()**0.6)

#
# Plot
#

#plt.imshow() is one way, but I'll use .contourf() and .contour()
# plt.imshow(removal_frac, cmap='plasma', interpolation='none', extents=<set bounds to match data>)

#Contour filled plot. Increase levels= as you prefer
plt.contourf(p_inlet_grid, t_inlet_grid, removal_frac, levels=25, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()

#Optionally overlay contour lines
#You could also use contour independently, making a plot out of the lines only
contours = plt.contour(p_inlet_grid, t_inlet_grid, removal_frac,
                       levels=7, colors='black', alpha=0.8)
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8)

plt.xlabel('$P^{inlet}$', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('$T^{inlet}$', fontsize=14)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 4)
plt.title(f'Removal fraction when Ptank={p_tank}')

plt.show()
```

In 3D:

[image]

```
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(p_inlet_grid, t_inlet_grid, removal_frac, cmap='plasma')
ax.set_xlabel('Pinlet')
ax.set_ylabel('Tinlet')
```

---

Adapting the OP's code where the computation occurs in a loop:

```
#Creating the 2D grid
P_inlet_vals, T_inlet_vals = np.meshgrid(P_inlet, T_inlet)
Removal_fraction = np.zeros_like(P_inlet_vals)

#Computing removal_fraction for each point in the grid
for row in range(len(T_inlet)):
    for col in range(len(P_inlet)):
        Removal_fraction[row, col] = removal_fraction(
            P_inlet_vals[row, col], T_inlet_vals[row, col], P_tank
        )
```

Comment: I can now determine the meshgrid, but am having trouble getting my array of z values since the propssi function will not take in an array. I tried something else, please see updated question.

Comment: I have updated the code at the bottom of my answer - does that help? If not, please report back what the error is.

Comment: I ran your code, and Jupyter Lab stalled out. My main problem at this point is trying to calculate my function value for each point on the grid and then somehow transforming that data into an array that MatPlotLib will plot correctly.

Comment: For troubleshooting, try reducing the size of `p_inlet` and `t_inlet` from 500 down to a smaller number like 10. It should run without crashing unless there's a bug. I've updated the plotting code to use contours rather than imshow, though the end result isn't too different.

Comment: this works now, thanks.

Comment: No worries. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `Removal_fractions` contains a vector of length 500, not a 2d-array. Your `H_inlet` is a vector of length 500, too, not a 500x500 matrix. You have to create a loop over all combinations of pressure and temperature.

```
    #Enthalpy of sap before flash tank
    H_inlet = []
    for P in P_inlet:
        H_inlet.append(cp.PropsSI('H',"P",P,"T",T_inlet,"water")) #J/kg
```

Comment: I also think that it is more comfortable to use matplotlib's `contourf` instead of `imshow`.